# WP User Query with meta queries

Tags: meta-query, wp-user-query

I'm having some problems when comparing integer values '>=' or '<=' with meta_queries with the WP_USER_QUERY.

Let say I've stored the following meta keys with the meta values below:

```
meta_key            meta_value

type                type1     
status              active
location            London
min_price           10000
max_price           20000
```

The query works fine for the meta keys 'type', 'status' and 'location'. But I'm having problems with the 'min_price' and 'max_price'.

Below you can find the code I used to retrieve a list of users with the above meta keys:

```
// Values
$type = 'type1';
$status = 'active';
$location = 'London';
$price = 15000;

// Query args
$args = array(
   'role' => 'end-user',
   'orderby' => 'ID',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => $status,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'location',
            'value' => $location,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'min_price',
            'value' => $price,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'max_price',
            'value' => $price,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
   )
);

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

// Get the results
$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check if we have users
if (!empty($users)) {
    // Loop through results
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user->ID;
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Users Found!'; 
}
```

This query returns me 'No Users Found!'. However if I use the same values stored for the 'min_price' and 'max_price' meta query, it works. E.g.:

```
array(
    'key' => 'min_price',
    'value' => 10000,
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
),
array(
    'key' => 'max_price',
    'value' => 20000,
    'compare' => '<=',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
),
```

Other values than 10000 and 20000 don't work. Any help please.

Comment: Just a quick question. In your code you use the same `$price` as min and max value?

Comment: Yes the `$price` is use to verify if it is '>=' min_price and '<=' max_price.

Comment: So you want all users >= 100 && <= 100, which would equal = 100, right?

Comment: If a user has 10000 as value for 'min_price' and 20000 as value for 'max_price' while `$price = 15000`, then I want all users where '15000 >= 10000' and '15000 <= 20000'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think your code says

Where `min_price` >= $price and `max_price` <= $price.

Try to switch the operands, like here:

```
    array(
        'key' => 'min_price',
        'value' => $price,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'max_price',
        'value' => $price,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
```

It works for 10.000 and 20.000 since you use the bigger/*equal* and lower/*equal* operator.